# Proving an inequality regarding the exponential function

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

[image]

I have to prove this inequality but I can't see how to start. Do I have to use the taylor expansion? Or what method should I use? Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please don't use an image for the question... it is not searchable... the best practice is to transcribe it with Mathjax.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to prove the Chernoff bound. Have you looked online for such proofs? There is a myriad of them.

Answer (score 0):

Since our domain that we're interested in is $(0, 1)$ we can substitute $\delta = 1 - x$:

$$x^x = e^{x\ln(x)}$$

$$ e^{-(1-x) -x\ln(x)}  \leq e^{-(1-x)^2/2}$$

$$ -(1-x) -x\ln(x)  \leq -\frac{1}{2}(1-x)^2$$
$$ -x\ln(x)  \leq -\frac{1}{2}(x^2 - 1)$$

$$\ln(x) \geq \frac{1}{2}(x- \frac{1}{x})$$

But this is implied  by the well-known [lower bound of the natural logarithm](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lower_Bound_of_Natural_Logarithm).